# How to encode a 32 bit ALAC from a RAW using FFmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, codec, audio-conversion, alac

Trying to compress a 32 bit floating point waveform (raw binary).
FLAC is out because it only goes up to 24 bits per sample.
ALAC can handle 32 bits per sample.

I can encode directly from RAW to ALAC with the following command:

```
ffmpeg -f f32le -ar 4000 -ac 1 -i ts1.raw -acodec alac ts1.m4a
```

Note this works with any data file.

I have tried to set 32 bit sample size with `-sample_fmt s32p` but it always prints the message:

```
[alac @ 0x55dbbcc98a00] encoding as 24 bits-per-sample
```

Decoding is done by:

```
ffmpeg -i ts1.m4a -f f32le -ar 4000 -ac 1 tsa.raw
```

I verify by loading the start and end raw files (`ts1.raw` vs `tsa.raw`) with Numpy (Python) and notice there is loss off precision. The result is closer to a 16 bit float but more precise (24 bit float makes sense). So basically I end up with a file containing 24 bit floats converted to 32 bit (lossy compression)!

How can I encode a 32 bits-per-sample lossless-compressed (for waveform data) file?

Comment: FFmpeg's ALAC encoder only supports 24-bit encoding.

Answer (score 2):

according to https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT212183
it is said that  `the entire Apple Music catalog is now also encoded using ALAC in resolutions ranging from 16-bit/44.1 kHz (CD Quality) up to 24-bit/192 kHz`
I am afraid u cant get a 32bit audio file